# Can We Permanently Change/Add the String in Html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, string

I am currently working on a project where inside a textbox users can write HTML codes and will add a new code when submitted ........I am using simple HTML, CSS, JS, and Jquery

And My main Question is

> " Can really we can change/ Add new HTML codes to our existing HTML
> permanently ?? "

eg:  index.html

```
<div class="main">
  <h1>Line 1</h1>
  <h1>Line 2</h1>
</div>

<div class="form">

     <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea5">Code here</label>
     <textarea class="form-control" id="FormControlTextarea" rows="16" spellcheck="false"> 
     </textarea>
     <button onClick="AddCode()"> Submit </button>

</div>
```

and anyhow I want to add a new `<h1>` tag

Eg:   user types in the textbox  `<h1>Hello</h1>`

Like this (*Ignore the preview box) [image]

And when The User Hits Submit the Code which is in the text Box (  `<h1>Hello</h1>` )
would be added inside index.html

like this:

```
 <div class="main">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <h1>Line 1</h1>
      <h1>Line 2</h1>
 </div>
```

Comment: Yes, you need a server side language to write the data somewhere.

Comment: You can't do that with only a script, CSS, and HTML, but you can do that. For that, you will need to run a server (can be on Node.js) and have a place to store your data. You can check it out for a start: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xVYa20DCUv0

Answer (score 0):

You can save html code inside database. When click on submit button, code can be added in database using ajax. Then you can fetch records from database to show it in div.